# scons error: no version of visual studio compiler found C/C++

Tags: c, visual-c++, scons

I am attempting to build [OpenWSN](https://github.com/openwsn-berkeley/openwsn-fw) using [Scons](http://www.scons.org/) and get the following output:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...

 ___                 _ _ _  ___  _ _
| . | ___  ___ ._ _ | | | |/ __>| \ |
| | || . \/ ._>| ' || | | |\__ \|   |
`___'|  _/\___.|_|_||__/_/ <___/|_\_|
     |_|                  openwsn.org

scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
default(["default"], [])

Usage: scons board=<b> toolchain=<tc> project

Where:
board: Board to build for.
    default: telosb
    actual: telosb

toolchain: Toolchain to use.
    default: mspgcc
    actual: mspgcc

jtag: Location of the board to JTAG the binary to.
    default:
    actual:

fet_version: Firmware version running on the MSP-FET430uif.
    default: 2
    actual: 2

bootload: Location of the board to bootload the binary on.
    default:
    actual:

verbose: Print complete compile/link comand.
    default: 0
    actual: 0

scons: done building targets.
```

It does not appear to have built anything, but rather is asking me which board and tool chain I wish to use.

My goal is to compile https://github.com/openwsn-berkeley/openwsn-fw/tree/develop/firmware/openos/bsp/chips/at86rf231

What is the easiest way to get the code for an AT86RF231 compiled?

Comment: @noisebelt - I ended up using the IAR workbench to compile code for  GINA. That was sufficient.

Comment: @user1068636 I think I just found a solution to this problem. Which compiler did you want to use? Could you add the actual scons error output to the output paragraph of your question (instead of just keeping it in the headline)?

Comment: `No version of Visual Studio...` is a generic Windows warning. It will likely be removed in SCons 2.3.3